# ModelForm Django Permissions

Tags: python-3.x, django

Как вывести поля разрешённые для конкретного пользователя?

Моя модель

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = [
        ('1', 'Создан'),
        ('2', 'Согласование'),
        ('3', 'Выполняется'),
        ('4', 'Выполнен'),
    ]

    WARRANTY = [
        ('1', '1 день'),
        ('2', '1 неделю'),
        ('3', '1 месяц'),
        ('4', 'Пол года'),
        ('5', '1 год'),
    ]

    SERVICE = [
        ('1', 'Разработка сайта LandingPage'),
        ('2', 'Разработка многостраничного сайта'),
        ('3', 'Обслуживание сайта'),
        ('4', 'Разработка индивидуального дизайна'),
    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)

    #user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'Пользователь')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, verbose_name = 'Наименование')
    service = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = SERVICE, verbose_name = 'Услуга')
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 32, default = '1', choices = STATUS, verbose_name = 'Статус')
    technical_task = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Техническое задание')
    the_timing = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Срок')
    butget = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Бюджет')
    warranty = models.CharField(max_length = 32, choices = WARRANTY, null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Гарантия')
    complete = models.IntegerField(default = 0, verbose_name = 'Процент выполнения')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Дата создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, verbose_name = 'Дата редактирования')

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            # Разрешения для поля услуги
            ('can_view_service', 'Can view service'),
            ('can_change_service', 'Can change service'),

            # Разрешения для поля срок
            ('can_view_the_timing', 'Can view the timing'),
            ('can_change_the_timing', 'Can change the timing'),

            # Разрешения для поля бюджет
            ('can_view_butget', 'Can view butget'),
            ('can_change_butget', 'Can change butget'),

            # Разрешение для поля гарантия
            ('can_view_warranty', 'Can view warranty'),
            ('can_change_warranty', 'Can change warranty'),

            # Разрешения для поля процент выполнения
            ('can_view_complete', 'Can view complete'),
            ('can_change_complete', 'Can change complete'),
        ]
```

Моя форма

```
class CreateOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

        fields = [
            'name', 'service', 'status', 'technical_task', 'the_timing', 'butget', 'warranty', 'complete',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'service': forms.Select(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'technical_task': forms.Textarea(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'the_timing': AdminDateWidget(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'butget': forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'warranty': forms.Select(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
            'complete': forms.NumberInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Как мне в форме проверить разрешения на поля у пользователя который заполняет форму?